# Hibernate does not delete, @PrePersist and @PreUpdate

Tags: java, hibernate

I have the following entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="accounts")
public class AccountEntity extends TimestampAbstractEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private int id;

}
```

TimestampAbstractEntity:

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class TimestampAbstractEntity implements Serializable{

    @Column(name = "created_at", columnDefinition = "DATETIME")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date createdAt;

    @Column(name = "updated_at", columnDefinition = "DATETIME")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date updatedAt;

    public Date getCreatedAt() {
        return createdAt;
    }

    @PrePersist
    public void setCreatedAt(Date createdAt) {
        this.createdAt = createdAt;
    }

    public Date getUpdatedAt() {
        return updatedAt;
    }

    @PreUpdate
    public void setUpdatedAt(Date updatedAt) {
        this.updatedAt = updatedAt;
    }
}
```

The delete method from Session is not working at all, not even a log is showed.
I tried a workaround using

```
getCurrentSession().createQuery(delete from yadada where id=:id).setInteger("id", id).executeUpdate();
```

Log pops pops up but nothing happens in the database, i am using hibernate-core 5.1.0.Final

And my configuration is:

```
Configuration configuration = new Configuration();

            configuration.setProperty("hibernate.connection.driver_class", "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            configuration.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect");
            configuration.setProperty("hibernate.current_session_context_class", "thread");
            configuration.setProperty("hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings", "false");
            configuration.setProperty("hibernate.show_sql", "true");

            configuration.addAnnotatedClass(AccountEntity.class);

            StandardServiceRegistryBuilder builder = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder()
                    .applySettings(configuration.getProperties());
            return configuration.buildSessionFactory(builder.build());
```

Comment: Just to double check, are you running the delete inside a transaction?

Comment: Use createSqlQuery, specific need of using hql ?

Comment: @Pace Either way does not work

Comment: @Mrunal Yes it has to be done either with HQL or .delete method but both does not work

Comment: which version of hibernate-entitymanager jar are you using ?

Comment: What is the return value of `executeUpdate()`?  If it is 0 then your query is not matching anything, if it is 1 then the transaction is not closing for some reason.  Also, shouldn't it be `delete from AccountEntity`?

Comment: @Pace 1 is returned, the transaction is "stuck" and what do  you mean by "delete from AccountEntity". I use hibernate-core 5.1.0.Final jar and mysql-connector 5.1.38

Comment: Your query says "delete from yadada" but your entity is named AccountEntity.  I wasn't sure if that was just a copy paste thing.  How are you starting your transaction?  Directly on the session or using something like @Transactional?

Comment: @Pace yadada is just an example. I have a session factory -> and then i call either create session or create session with transaction

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try the following and tell me what results you get?

```
public void deleteAccount(SessionFactory sessionFactory, Integer entityId) {
    Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    session.getTransaction().begin();
    AccountEntity account = session.get(AccountEntity.class, entityId);
    session.delete(account);
    session.getTransaction().commit();
    session.getTransaction().begin();
    account = session.get(AccountEntity.class, entityId);
    System.out.println(account); //Should be null!
    session.getTransaction().rollback();
}
```

Or if you want to use a query:

```
public void deleteAccount(SessionFactory sessionFactory, Integer entityId) {
    Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    session.getTransaction().begin();
    session.createQuery("delete from AccountEntity where id=:id").setInteger("id", id).executeUpdate();
    session.getTransaction().commit();
    session.getTransaction().begin();
    account = session.get(AccountEntity.class, entityId);
    System.out.println(account); //Should be null!
    session.getTransaction().rollback();
}
```